# Searching for the timepicker like Mozilla thunderbird

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have been searching and googling for the timepicker like Mozilla thunderbird (see attachment). I need only a timepicker not a datetimepicker. I hope that it is in jQuery so that I can add this timepicker in the Joomla backend.
Does any one know of this exist as open source. Or a timepicker which comes close to it. 
[Timepicker Mozilla thunderbird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56lte.jpg)

[image: Timepicker Mozilla thunderbird - expand the 5 min. to 1 min]

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select date and time, the native Calendar form field will work, using `default="now" format="%h:%i:%s"`, thus, the user can select a date and time, but only the time is saved to the database. If you do not want the user to select a date, you could always just override either the calendar field layout, or simply hide the date selectors with something like `.calendar-header, .daysrow {display: none;}`. Simple, but effective.